# ORDER BY an Alias in SQLIte

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I am trying to use ORDER BY to order the output of my query by the resulting column after doing the following, but the order of that newly created column remains random. What can I do to fix this issue using this (generalized) code:

```
SELECT *, (column_one / column_two) AS 'Alias'

  FROM data_set

WHERE column_one > column_two

ORDER BY 'Alias'
;
```

Comment: I'd try `ORDER BY Alias`. (Since order by string literal constant makes no sense.)

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 3):

Only use single quotes for string and date constants -- never for column aliases.  That will fix your problem:

```
SELECT *, (column_one / column_two) AS Alias
FROM data_set
WHERE column_one > column_two
ORDER BY Alias
```

Ordering by the string `'Alias'` is not going to do what you want.